# Hibernate: get rid of selected data stored in heap after reading it

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I got this app that all it does is perform selects and after I'm done reading that I no longer need the objects at all.

I got no problem reading the data, as the queries are very atomic. My problem is the big amount of data there, so eventually the old stored objects in heap lead to a out of memory exception.

How can I perform selects that get rid of the previous objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object will be referenced by the NH session cache. To get rid of them, you could

- Use the [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession)
- `Clear` the session after the query (which also removes other objects from the session)
- `Evict` each of the objects
- Using a query that doesn't load entities, but values or dtos (`select a, b` or `select new Dto(a, b)`) which doesn't use the cache at all.

Comment: I believe my whole problem is the design I have for this desktop app (which seems to be automatically session-per-thread situation), StatelessSession looks like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Objects that don't have references to them will be garbage collected and can't cause out of memory exceptions. So if you do get such exception then objects are still referenced and you need to find out what holds them.

If error is caused by too large result set, you could consider using pagination via `setMaxResults()` and `setFirstResult()` or  [Query.iterate()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#iterate%28%29).

Comment: ok, this means in theory that if I have 10 A objects, each with a collection of 1000 B objects, it should collect 1001 objects 10 times?

Comment: With 10 A objects and 1000 B objects in each of them, you probably only need to increase heap size. It will be trickier if you have few millions of A objects with few millions on B objects. In this case you may want to iterate over list or get pages with, for example, 1000 A objects. You may also need to evict objects that you processed as suggested in other answer. `scroll` is a good thing, too.

Answer (score 0):

After you are done working with the entity you queried, you should evict it from the Session cache and then dereference it, at which point, it will be eligible for garbage collection.  See the examples in the section titled [Managing the Caches](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-sessioncache) of the Hibernate Guide.  Here's an example:

```
ScrollableResult cats = sess.createQuery("from Cat as cat").scroll(); //a huge result set
while ( cats.next() ) {
    Cat cat = (Cat) cats.get(0);
    doSomethingWithACat(cat);
    sess.evict(cat);
}
```

Comment: something odd, I'm creating my entityManager once and then I return the same em on other calls. If I get a session out of that entityManager the session is empty

Comment: If you're using JPA 2.0, you should call EntityManager.detach(Object) instead of session.evict().  Otherwise, call EntityManager.getDelegate, cast that to a Session and use evict.

Comment: I'll give a try to detach later. Just don't understand why my (Session)getDelegate is empty already and the MTA dump says the objects are still there